# "に"の連続使用は避けるべきでしょうか？

Tags: grammar

```
A {
    B {
       C {
           D
       }
    }
}
```

以上の構造を説明したい時に、僕はいつも「AにBにCにはDがあります」とか「AにBにCにDについて」というな言葉を使います。自分が書いた文章を声出して読んでみたら、何か違和感を感じます。こういう場合は言い換え言葉、またもっといい表現の書き方がございましたら、ご教示をお願いします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

質問で示された「構造」が具体的に何かによって適切な表現は変わると思います（そもそも「に」が適切かも問題になり，自分の想像した範囲では「の」でつなぐほうが適切なことが多いように思いました）．
強いて一般的にいえば，多少冗長になりますがたとえば

> AにはBが，BにはCが，CにはDがあります

という言い方にするのがよいとおもいます．上記の通り具体的にどういうふうに階層を追っていくかによって表現は変わります．いくつか思いついたものを列挙しておきます

- 京都市は，日本の，近畿地方の，京都府にあります (Japan { Kinki { Kyoto-pref { Kyoto-city }}）
- 細胞のなかにはミトコンドリアがあり，その中には DNA が含まれています (cells { mitochondria { DNA }})
- 自然数の中で1と自身以外で割り切れない数を素数といい，そのうち差が2である組を双子素数といいます．

いずれにせよ，助詞を連続して使うよりは階層を明記するほうがよいでしょう．

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。質問に「構造」はXMLやプログラミングにオブジェクトの構造です。例えXMLの場合、`A{ B { C { D }}}`にDの用途について説明したいですが、「Dとは～」だけなら、Dの位置が把握できないので、階層も表す必要があります。